# How to Implement off chain Keepers for Decentralize Perpetual Exchanges like GMX.io?

Tags: ethereum, solidity, decentralized-applications, chainlink-keepers

I'm attempting to clone gmx.io. I understand most of the on-chain and Dex concepts, but I'm stumped on how to establish an off-chain. Keepers they did not opensource the code for that, so could you kindly assist me in determining what the specific usage of the keepers was and how I would implement keepers?

I've included some relevant articles below.

- https://gmxio.gitbook.io/gmx/contracts
- https://gmx-io.notion.site/gmx-io/GMX-Technical-Overview-47fc5ed832e243afb9e97e8a4a036353
- https://medium.com/perpdex/gmx-research-9da560f1e447
- https://liamhieuvu.com/how-gmx-limit-order-and-long-short-work

I tried developing a basic listener that monitors the price of the token 24 hours a day, seven days a week, and temporarily stores all orders, and when any order limit price matches the asset price, I call the smartcontract function to start a position.

But it isn't working or performing as expected, so I wanted to find out exactly what I needed to accomplish, what tools and services I required, and how I would implement it in accordance with the standards.

Comment: This topic is good fit for StackOverflowo discussion as it is too open ended. Try ethereum.stackexchange.com instead. Also please include more details in the question and study on StackExchange FAQs how to ask good questions.